# Overlay on Responsive Image for horizontal Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an overlay for responsive images in a horizontal gallery.
The overlay `div` in the `li` has `position` and a large `z-index` value but still displays on background of the image.
When I try to do `absolute` for an image with higher `z-index` the horizontal scrolling for image fails.

See the demo: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6hho2sL/)

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#thumbsList {
  height: 76%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  top: 13%;
  left: 80px;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 13%;
  position: absolute;
}
#thumbsList li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#thumbsList li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.backStrip {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 22;
  position: fixed;
  width: 253px;
  top: 43px;
  height: 79px;
  left: 85px;
}
#infoText {
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#mainContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid #2D2D2D;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#thumbsButtons {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 46%;
  z-index: 22;
}
#counterContainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
}
#thumbsButtons li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 11px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#thumbsButtons li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nextArrow {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 43%;
  z-index: 13333;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidelogo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 67px;
  height: 258px;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
.headerInfo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 333;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
}
.thumbOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 13111133;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div class="backStrip"> <span id="infoText">Written By Banmeet Singh</span>

  </div>
  <ul id="thumbsButtons"></ul> <span id="nextArrow">></span>
  <span id="sidelogo">Thinking Forward</span>

  <ul id="thumbsList">
    <li>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" /> <span class="headerInfo">Josh Kloss</span>

    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="thumbOverlay"><span>adasd</span> 
      </div>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="counterContainer">3 of 10</div>
```

Check the Second Image. I have added the overlay to that.

Comment: You can see the .overlay div at the second horizontal list item.Now it is in back of the image. i want it in front of image..

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r6hho2sL/3/)?

Comment: @Antony yes please tell me in answer how you did that and i will  verify you.,

Comment: @Antony yes but there is a gap between images when i resize the browser... i mea gaps between List Items.,

Comment: @Antony when i resize my rbowser the image width i guess is less than li width and when i navigate it jerks and automatically fits. But why not it fits in the first time when browser is reloaded?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean. First of all the overlay does not appear in the background. It just doesn't know its height and stays at the bottom of the image. Second there are gaps between images in your original demo, and they are always there whether you resize the browser or not. And I see nothing jerking when I resize the browser, only the gallery retaining the scrolling position as the images are resized, so it appears that the images are moving. If you want the images to stay as you resize the browser, you will have to use JavaScript to adjust the scroll position.

Comment: the gaps are because of the <li>s are 'inline' and white-space (gap) is 'space' (like in text). you use 'block' elements in 'inline', that is bad. to achieve desired result you can use css3 features ('flex', 'calc', 'vh', 'vw').

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini is [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117027/overlay-on-responsive-image-for-horizontal-image/33291648#33291648) solves your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#thumbsList li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

are you expecting this kind of result?
see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6hho2sL/2/)

Comment: It does fix overlay but now the li and the images are of very big size. Not Responsove..

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/r6hho2sL/11/

here I made some modifications to your code:

1. I used JQuery to adjust the width of the overlay element on window re-size event so that it would keep its responsive behavior

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( ".thumbOverlay" ).width($(".forward").width());
});
$( ".thumbOverlay" ).width($(".forward").width());
```

2. I used (divs and spans) instead of list (ul and li)
3. I modified the css classes

   ```
   .thumbOverlay {
       top: 0;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 13111133;
       background-color: black;
       color: white;
       height: 100%;
       display: inline;
   }

   #thumbsList span {
   display: inline;
   margin-left: -4px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Marc Andre, your fiddle(s) code is, unfortunately, rather leaky and inconsistent. So, instead of patching and rearranging it, I took the liberty of starting from scratch staying as close to your original idea as possible.

For a quick look, check my Pen on CODEPEN [Responsive filmstrip and thumblist](http://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/ZbrpQO)

Where did you go wrong?
First of all, I don't intend to pick on you, I am just being honest:

You didn't use '**position**' correctly on your elements, which (probably) resulted in a confusing (hair-pulling, I guess) onscreen output.

Two general rules:

1) **parent-element => position: relative, child-element => position: absolute**.
Both can have any kind of width/height (%, px), but the child values are relative to the parent-element.

2) **child-element => position: fixed**. Width/height/position are relative to the browser window, ALWAYS.

You mixed the two rules and got yourself running in circles. To break free you should do:

```
/* Generally accepted (and working) init of HTML and BODY */
html, body         { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
body               { max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto }
/* margin: 0 auto will center BODY onscreen if max-width < 100% */


#thumbsList        { position: absolute /* relative to BODY!!! which is a parent */ }

#thumbsList li     { position: relative /* while a child of UL, it is a parent of IMG */ }

#thumbsList li img { position: absolute /* child of LI absolute coords relative to LI */ }
```

No further '**position**'ing should be needed for **#thumbslist** (only sizing, styling and such).
Again unfortunately, because of the number of (logic) errors, your CSS requires to be redesigned (IMHO that is).

**UPDATE**

As you may have seen by now, the code works on Codepen and standalone in the latest IE11, FF and CH (all W7, I still need to check mobile).

What I essentially created is a strip of stacked flexbox layout layers. Once you master the flexbox techniques, you wil see that it has lots of advantages over regular (inline-)block techniques. Drawbacks too, I will point them out where applicable.

To easily understand my (very down to earth) flexbox workflow I always ask what basic layout is needed:

- a column of rows or a row of columns
- wrapping or not
- justification (often `justify-content: space-between`, you may want to read into this)

Nesting and trickery will come later...

Dissecting your requirements: you actually need a regular webpage, but instead of nicely placed blocks, you need them stacked, hence the need for **layers**

Answer (score 1):

## Why is this happening?

This is not an issue with `z-index` as `.thumbOverlay` is stacked on top of the image. The issue is that `.thumbOverlay` has a percentage `height` which means it will take up the full `height` of its container. In this case the container is a `li` which has been setup as `display: inline;` so its height will be as high as its line box.

### What can you do?

For your overlay to work you either need `height: 100%;` to calculate the correct `height`.

#### Method 1: Make the list item inline-block

If you make the `li` `display: inline-block;` then you will be able to set its `height`.

- Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;` on `#thumbsList li`
- Add `height: 100%;` to `#thumbsList li` to make the `li` the `height` of the `ul`
- Change `max-width: 100%;` to `max-width: calc(100vw - 96px);` on `#thumbsList li img`. This will ensure that the `img` takes up the full width of the viewport, minus the `border`s and `position`ing applied to the `#mainContainer` and `#thumbsList`

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#thumbsList {
    height: 76%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
    top: 13%;
    left: 80px;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 13%;
    position: absolute;
}
#thumbsList li {
    /*display: inline;REMOVE THIS*/
    display: inline-block; /*ADD THIS*/
    height: 100%; /*ADD THIS*/
    position: relative;
}
#thumbsList li img {
    /*max-width: 100%; REMOVE THIS*/
    max-width: calc(100vw - 96px); /*ADD THIS*/
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.backStrip {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 22;
    position: fixed;
    width: 253px;
    top: 43px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 85px;
}
#infoText {
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 8px solid #2D2D2D;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#thumbsButtons {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6%;
    left: 46%;
    z-index: 22;
}
#counterContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
}
#thumbsButtons li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 11px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: verdana;
}
#thumbsButtons li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nextArrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 43%;
    z-index: 13333;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sidelogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 67px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
.headerInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 333;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 13111133;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    /*display: inline; REMOVE THIS*/
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="backStrip"> 
        <span id="infoText">Written By Banmeet Singh</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="thumbsButtons"></ul> <span id="nextArrow">></span>
    <span id="sidelogo">Thinking Forward</span>
    <ul id="thumbsList">
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" /> <span class="headerInfo">Josh Kloss</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbOverlay"><span>adasd</span> </div>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="counterContainer">3 of 10</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhqg2zg3/2/

#### Method 2: Make the overlay relative to the list

If you make `.thumbOverlay` position relative to the `ul` you will be able to get the `height` from the `ul` instead.

- Remove `position: relative;` from `#thumbsList li`. This will stop `.thumbOverlay` from being relative to it
- Remove `left: 0px;` from `.thumbOverlay`. This will ensure that its left position is kept at where it is initially drawn

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#thumbsList {
    height: 76%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
    top: 13%;
    left: 80px;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 13%;
    position: absolute;
}
#thumbsList li {
    display: inline;
    /*position: relative; REMOVE THIS*/
}
#thumbsList li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.backStrip {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 22;
    position: fixed;
    width: 253px;
    top: 43px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 85px;
}
#infoText {
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 8px solid #2D2D2D;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#thumbsButtons {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6%;
    left: 46%;
    z-index: 22;
}
#counterContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
}
#thumbsButtons li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 11px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: verdana;
}
#thumbsButtons li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nextArrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 43%;
    z-index: 13333;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sidelogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 67px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
.headerInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 333;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 13111133;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /*left: 0px; REMOVE THIS*/
    top: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="backStrip"> 
        <span id="infoText">Written By Banmeet Singh</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="thumbsButtons"></ul> <span id="nextArrow">></span>
    <span id="sidelogo">Thinking Forward</span>
    <ul id="thumbsList">
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" /> <span class="headerInfo">Josh Kloss</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbOverlay"><span>adasd</span> </div>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="counterContainer">3 of 10</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmuqvLpm/

*It's worth noting that the way you are currently scaling your images will lead to distortion as they are not going to keep their aspect ratio. This is because the `height` of the image is remaining static while the `width` scales. It may be worth doing something like this instead:*

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#thumbsList {
    height: 76%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
    top: 13%;
    left: 80px;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 13%;
    position: absolute;
}
#thumbsList li {
    /*display: inline;REMOVE THIS*/
    display: inline-block; /*ADD THIS*/
    vertical-align: middle;  /*ADD THIS*/
    position: relative;
}
#thumbsList li img {
    width: calc(100vw - 96px); /*ADD THIS*/
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.backStrip {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 22;
    position: fixed;
    width: 253px;
    top: 43px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 85px;
}
#infoText {
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 8px solid #2D2D2D;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#thumbsButtons {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6%;
    left: 46%;
    z-index: 22;
}
#counterContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
}
#thumbsButtons li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 11px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: verdana;
}
#thumbsButtons li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nextArrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 43%;
    z-index: 13333;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sidelogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 67px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
.headerInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 333;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 13111133;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    /*display: inline; REMOVE THIS*/
}
#thumbsList:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="backStrip"> 
        <span id="infoText">Written By Banmeet Singh</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="thumbsButtons"></ul> <span id="nextArrow">></span>
    <span id="sidelogo">Thinking Forward</span>
    <ul id="thumbsList">
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" /> <span class="headerInfo">Josh Kloss</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbOverlay"><span>adasd</span> </div>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="counterContainer">3 of 10</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwxznmhy/

Comment: Thanks @Crispy-George. I did wonder if I had missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Add this.

```
#thumbsList li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Issue -**

since `li` is made `display:inline`, it is not taking up 100% height of your `ul` i.e. `#thumbsList`.

**Solution-**

After making your `li` `display:inline-block` and adding `height:100%`, `li` element took entire height of `ul` and `thumbOverlay` `div` which is a child elemt of `li` also took up 100% height.

Comment: Why down vote? is there anything wrong with the answer?