# Block that simultes images {width: 100%; height : auto} behaviour

Tags: html, css

I want to create the following layout :

[image]

Is a stripe of a variable number of images that have various widths and heights, that are:

- proportional
- scaled at the same height;
- and the sum of their widths are equal to the parent width.

***It's kind of complicated to express myself;

I was wondering if it's possible for a block to simulate the `img` neat proportion behavior  when you set a width to a percentage and it calculates the height of it `auto`magically.

I've made up a diagram that maybe explain better what I want to achieve :

[image]

I want for the image to have collectively 100% width of the parent element, scaled with at the same height without loosing their proportion.

I've tried various implementations trying to figure out a way in which I can translate compute a percentage height in css that fills all the width for a block, just how the image behaves when there are `{width: 100%; height : auto}` properties.

So here is what I've got so far :

#### Strike #1, tried a simple solution

Problem: container height must be predefined.

```css
.container {
 width : 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 50px; /* I would like to say here auto */
}

.image-wrapper {
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%; 
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/100x200" />
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/10x80" />
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Strike #2, display: table anyone ?

Problem: Don't even need to mention it, images are cropped the container size doesn't follow its parent size .

```css
.container-wrapper {
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
 width : 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%; 
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/100x200" />
        </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/10x80" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***I must say that I am looking for a HTML/CSS solution without the involvement of JavaScript code.

Do you have a clue on how can I approach this ?

Comment: I'm still confused what you're asking. You want to set a percentage width and have the height be automatic... But automatic to *what*? A ratio of the width? e.g. the height is always half the width?

Comment: Automatic to the proportion formed by the images displayed one next to each other.  Look at the diagram.

Comment: So is true that the height of container is variable?

Comment: Yes, it should be ... I've tried different approaches but nothing seems to work out just with css. So javascript is the solution here

Answer (score 1):

So a trick I just came up with is to use the automagic scaling of an image to scale the containing filmstrip `div`, but hide it with opacity (in a real example, I'd use a transparent `.png` as well). This sets the height of the filmstrip relative to its width. If you want your filmstrip to be 5:4 or 16:9 or whatever, just change the proportions of the `.magic` image.

The container inside is then set to be absolutely positioned so it inherits the size of the `.magic` image.

The images themselves are set to take up the full height of the filmstrip, and are given different widths. The actual image is set with `background-image` which uses `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` to fill the `div`.

```css
.filmstrip {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
    /* just to make it easier to see what's going on */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.magic {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  
    /* we don't actually want to see this, we're just using it for it's ratio */
    opacity: 0;
}
.contents {
    position: absolute;
    top:  0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right:  0;
}
.contents .image {
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    
    /* just to make it easier to see what's going on */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contents .wide {
    width: 30%;
}
.contents .narrow {
     width: 10%
}
```

```html
<div class="filmstrip">
    <img class="magic" src="http://placehold.it/400x100" />
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="wide image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x100');"></div>
        <div class="narrow image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x100');"></div>
        <div class="wide image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x100');"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Browser support should be: Chrome 3+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Opera 10+, Safari 4.1+** which is basically because of the use of `background-cover`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my [stackoverflow 33117027 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117027/overlay-on-responsive-image-for-horizontal-image) in which I made suggestions about creating a **filmstrip**. It has a reference to an eleborate Codepen example. You can easily strip/add what you need...